# custom css scrollbar issue with webkit browsers

Tags: html, css, webkit

I have created a custom scroll bar which seem to be working fine on firefox, however i'm having an issue with my scroll appearing on screen in a webkit browser. [Click here](http://iamnatesmithen.com/bodyworks/product-details.php)

```
 #product-desc{
        top: 270px;
        left: 20px;
        right: 20px;
        bottom: 20px;
        height: 90px;
        max-width: 350px;
        overflow-x: hidden;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }


    #product-desc :: -webkit-scrollbar{
        width: 12px;
    }

    #product-desc :: -webkit-scrollbar-track{
        border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    }

    #product-desc :: -webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
        border-radius: 10px;
         -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
         color: #000;
        }
```

Does anyone know how i can resolve this issue?

Comment: Custom scroll bars are a *super* bad idea, and you should avoid them.

Comment: why is that? Aren't supported in most browsers?

Comment: Because the scroll-area-within-scroll-area user experience is really awful. The browser window already has a scroll bar. You should let it do its job.

Comment: ok mate, that's your opinion but it doesn't really answer my post question... i'm just doing what has been signed off by the client

Comment: This works for me in Chrome 21.0.1180.89. FWIW Google uses CSS-styled (`:: -webkit-scrollbar-*`) scrollbars all over the place in their apps. As long as it **is** the scrollbar (versus custom elements) and looks like a scrollbar, I don't think its a major UX problem (user agents are free to override/ignore).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are the pseudo elements themselves. The actual parts of the scrollbars.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar              { /* 1 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-button       { /* 2 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track        { /* 3 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  { /* 4 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb        { /* 5 */ }
::-webkit-scrollbar-corner       { /* 6 */ }
::-webkit-resizer                { /* 7 */ }
```

You may have a look at **[Custom Scrollbars in WebKit](http://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)**

You may also go through **[Styling scrollbars the Webkit way - CSS3](http://www.css3.info/styling-scrollbars-the-webkit-way/)**